# Connectedness of the comb space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Please, I need some help with this exercise

Consider the space

$X=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \{\frac{1}{n}\}\times[0,1]\cup ([0,1]\times\{0\})\cup(\{0\}\times [0,1]),$

With the topology of subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $X$ is connected but not locally connected

Comment: the basics, but really I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]Connectedness:
The space is even path-connected as you can readily specify a path from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$ via $(x_1,0)$ and $(x_2,0)$.

If $X$ were locally connected, you would find in each neighbourhood of $(0,1)$ a connected open subset. But each such open neighbourhood contains some point $(\frac1n,1)$ and can be shown to be disconnected by considering the disjoint open subsets given by $x<\frac1n$ and $x>\frac1{n+1}$, respectively.

Comment: Am I correct? Here there is no way of uploading the picture. please verify my drawing.

Comment: I will surely delete the picture. sorry for altering the answer.

Comment: By considering $(X,\mathscr T_{X})$ as the subspace topology of usual topology of $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: I got the separation of the slice in the open ball(say B). $U=B\cap \{(t,y)\mathbb R^2:t<x\}\cap X$ and $V=B\cap \{(t,y)\mathbb R^2:t>x\}\cap X$ are the separation right? so it is not locally connected.

Comment: Am I correct?I request you to verify.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen CAn you please explain the last line of the answer."can be shown to be disconnected by considering the disjoint open subsets given by x<1/n and x>1/(n+1), respectively." I am not able to understand how open neighbourhood is proved disconnected? Can you please explain in a bit detail?