# Compact connected, not locally connected

Tags: general-topology

Here is the example about compact, connected which is not locally connected.

Sine Curve which is

$S=\{<x,\sin(1/x)>: x\in(0,1]\}\cup\{<0,y>:y\in[-1,1]\}$

it is compact because closed and bounded, also it connected. But it is not locally connected. Is it right?

Are there  others  examples?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: It isn't clear whether the balance of your Question is about the Topologist's Sine Curve, and how to show it is not locally connected (or prove the other properties), or about identifying other examples.  The "Related" Questions shown at right sidebar on the desktop site may give you some ideas.  You can also try [this Search](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22not+locally+connected%22).

Comment: Yes, the topologist’s sine curve is compact, connected, and not locally connected. Another such example is the [comb space](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223715/connectedness-of-the-comb-space). The [closed infinite broom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_broom) is yet another example.

Comment: Thank  you very much, your answer is completely prefect

Answer (score 1):

Here are the results from [Pi-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org). You can view the [search result](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=compact%2Bconnected%2B%7Elocallyconnected) to learn more about each space.

Alexandroff Square

Closed Topologist's Sine Curve

Extended Topologist's Sine Curve

One Point Compactification of the Rationals

The Closed Infinite Broom

The Integer Broom

Comment: Thanks, it is help as well