# Show that if U contains one of the points (0, 0) and (0, 1), then it contains the other as well.

Tags: general-topology

Consider the subset
$$S = \big\{(0, 0),(0, 1)\big\}\  \bigcup\big(\displaystyle\cup_{n=1}^\infty L_n\big)$$
of $\Bbb R^2$ with the standard topology from $\Bbb R^2$, where
$$L_n = \big\{(1/n,y): 0\leq y\leq 1\big\}$$
for all $n ≥ 1$. Let $U$ be a non-empty subset of $S$ which is both open and closed in $S$.

Show that if $U$ contains one of the points $(0, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$, then it contains the other as well.

Comment: What you have tried? What is your thought? Please try to write something.

Comment: The hint given was to show that if the intersection of U and Ln is not empty, then Ln is contained within U, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: **As you have written I have edited.** Probably you are missing something. Is the set $\{(x,0):0\leq x\leq 1\}$ contained in $S$?

Comment: The question does not say it is, only the points (0,0) and (0,1)

Comment: It is not an answer to your question. But will help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223715/connectedness-of-the-comb-space Can you complete your argument now?

Comment: $L_n \cap U$ is clopen in $L_n$. Fact: in a connected space $X$ the only clopen subsets are $\emptyset$ and $X$. So if $U \cap L_n \neq \emptyset$, we must have $L_n \cap U = L_n$ by connectedness of $L_n$. It follows that $L_n \subseteq U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(0,0) \in U$. Then as $(\frac1n, 0) \to (0,0)$ we know that for some $N$ we have

$$\forall n \ge N: (\frac1n, 0) \in U$$

All sets $L_n=\{\frac1n\} \times [0,1] \simeq [0,1]$ are connected so if $U$ intersects $L_n$ we have that $L_n \subseteq U$ (or we'd have a non-trivial clopen subset $L_n \cap U$ of $L_n$). So from the previous fact we then have

$$\forall n \ge N: L_n \subseteq U$$ and as $(\frac1n,1) \in L_n$ and these converge to $(0,1)$, we get by closedness of $U$ that $(0,1) \in U$.

So $(0,0) \in U$ implies $(0,1) \in U$ and the reverse is also true by an analogous argument.